# Nodejs Youtube : Spawn unknown error

Tags: node.js, download, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-dl

My code in nodejs is like this :-

```
var fs = require('fs');
var youtubedl = require('youtube-dl');
var video = youtubedl('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90AiXO1pAiA',
  // Optional arguments passed to youtube-dl.

  // Additional options can be given for calling `child_process.execFile()`.
  );

// Will be called when the download starts.

video.on('info', function(info) {
  console.log('Download started');
  console.log('filename: ' + info.filename);
  console.log('size: ' + info.size);
});

video.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('myvideo.mp4'));
```

I get this error:-

> SPAWN unknown

You can also suggest an alternative way of making youtube downloader.

Comment: [this link](https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/issues/478) may help you

Comment: @9275462 see if my answer works for you.

Comment: it takes infinite to replace them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have same problem on Windows, I fixed it as:

Step 1:
Goto this [link](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html): https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html

Step 2:
Download [Windows exe (sig - SHA256 7071c7a2.....................)](https://yt-dl.org/downloads/2018.04.09/youtube-dl.exe)

Step 3:
Replace it at `\node_modules\youtube-dl\bin`

Step 4:
Run your code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const youTube = require('youtube-dl');
const video = youTube('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90AiXO1pAiA');

// called when the download starts.
video.on('info', function(info) {
    console.log('Download started');
    console.log('filename: ' + info.filename);
    console.log('size: ' + info.size);
});

video.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('downloads/downloaded_video.mp4'));
```

Step 5:
Expected console output:

```
/*  Sample Output   */
/*
    Download started
    filename: lol-90AiXO1pAiA.webm
    size: 1029843
    NOTE: File will be downloaded in downloads folder
*/
```

for complete files and running project:

Clone node-cheat [youtube_download_videos](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/blob/master/random/small_tasks/youtube-videos/download_script.js), run `node download_script.js` followed by `npm i youtube-dl`.

Comment: iam using youtube-dl-wrap and my node_modules has no youtube-dl folder